# NextJS CSP header destroying PDFtron iframe content

Tags: reactjs, iframe, next.js, content-security-policy, pdftron

I recently added CSP header to my project.
At the same time, I am also using PDFTron webviewer in my project.
As you know, PDFTron webviewer is rendered in an iframe and after adding CSP headers, I'm getting below error - related frame-ancestors.

[image]

**Question1** is how can I add a frame-ancestors header to the PDFtron webviewer to bypass this error?

**Question2** is the second error related with cross domain is not fixable by adding my domains to `configorigin.txt`, is it related with the csp header setting?

Answer (score 2):

*To Question1:* Just change `frame-ancestors 'none'` to the `frame-ancestors 'self'` (or to `frame-ancestors localhost:*` if in your particular browser the `'self'` token does not cover a `localhost:port_number`) to allow embedding PDF webviewer.

*To Question2:* I think the second error is CSP-related (side effect of CSP blocking) because `localhost` should not be a cross-origin resource since main page is loaded with the same host name and port number `http://localhost:3000`.

Comment: Hey, granty, thank you for the answer.
Regarding the first question,  I know I need to add `frame-ancestors` header to pdftron webviewer since it's embedded in an iframe, what I am asking is how / where can I add the header in the pdftron project. I tried to add it to the index.html as a meta tag, but it didn't work.

Comment: (1) `frame-ancestors` is not supported in meta tag, but only in HTTP header. (2) you have already publish CSP HTTP header since you see a blocking in the browser console. Check `next.config.js` file on `next-secure-headers`/`next-safe` packages presence or `headers()` function call - these can publich CSP header. You have to modify `frame-ancestors` there.

Comment: My understanding is `frame-ancestors` header should be set inside the iframe, am I wrong?
I tried to change the header value in next.config.js, but the result is the same "refused to frame localhost .... frame-ancestors: none" - means it's not working for iframe.

Comment: Yes, `frame-ancestors` header should be set inside the iframe. "*refused to frame localhost .... frame-ancestors: none*" means you did not change CSP header. After changing it should be `frame-ancestors 'self'` or `frame-ancestors localhost:*` in the violation message.